# return 0 if two values are zero

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
 <?php
    $pickuptime = date("H",strtotime($_COOKIE['stm_calc_pickup_date_1'] ));
    if($pickuptime > 9 && $pickuptime < 20 ) { 
        $nonworking_pick = 0; 
    } else { 
        $nonworking_pick = 10;
    }
    $returntime = date("H",strtotime($_COOKIE['stm_calc_return_date_1'] ));

    if($returntime > 9 && $returntime < 20 ) { 
        $nonworking_return = 0; 
    } else { 
        $nonworking_return = 10;
    }

    $total_non_working = $nonworking_return +  $nonworking_pick;
       ;
?>
```

It says if the pick up time is from 9 to 20 then give 0 else 10, same for return but I also need to add the consideration that if the pick up time and the return time are not selected to give 0 also.

Comment: How do you know if a time was not selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if(!$pickuptime && !$returntime){ $nonworking_pick = 0; }
```

The ! means "not." So, "if not $pickuptime and not $returntime."

"Not" means "not true." The variables will be "not true" if they are blank or zero.

UPDATE:

You may need to use something other than !, if your "not selected" value is something other than blank or zero.